# Hadoop Datanode is not starting

Tags: hadoop

Curently, I have installed Hadoop in my Ubuntu system. And I started it. Here are the details:

krish@krish-VirtualBox:~$ start-dfs.sh
14/10/20 13:16:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Starting namenodes on [localhost]

```
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-krish-namenode-krish-VirtualBox.out

localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-krish-datanode-krish-VirtualBox.out

Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-krish-secondarynamenode-krish-VirtualBox.out

14/10/20 13:16:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

krish@krish-VirtualBox:~$ start-yarn.sh

starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-krish-resourcemanager-krish-VirtualBox.out

localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-krish-nodemanager-krish-VirtualBox.out

krish@krish-VirtualBox:~$ jps

3065 NodeManager

2800 SecondaryNameNode

2941 ResourceManager

3307 Jps

2497 NameNode

krish@krish-VirtualBox:~$
```

I just want to know if all things are perfect in it. I do not see Datanode in the checklist.

Comment: I see no errors message, are you able to import/export data in your cluster ?

Comment: Obviously the datanode didn't start correctly. Check the datanode logs for clues.

Answer (score 2):

stop the cluster .

if you have specifically defined tmp directory location in core-site.xml then remove all files under those directory .

if you have specifically defined data node and namenode directory in hdfs-site.xml then delete all the files under those directories .

if you have not defined anything in core-site or hdfs-site then please remove all the files under /tmp/hadoop-*nameofyourhadoop user

format the namenode

it should work